# Regex to find only the second date

Tags: regex

This is an example line from a csv file:

```
A|ZHZ020|SAP|000005325602345|05.11.2015|37,58|EUR|+|I|2,363200|17895,22|05.11.2015|08|XY
```

I want to search only for the *last* date (ie the *second* in this case). My regex:

```
\W[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}\W
```

doesn't work as desired, because it matches both dates.

I don't have any idea of how to do that. Is it possible to write the regex in a way that says "skip the first match"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative look ahead:

```
\W\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4}\W(?!.*\W\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4}\W)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/FLB7oQXovI).

The negative look ahead ensures a match only occurs if there *isn't* a match somewhere later in the input (which is logically equivalent to matching only the *last* hit).

Also notice the use of the shorter `\d` ("digit") instead of the longer `[0-9]` (character class containing all digit chars).

Comment: Ah, nice , now it works, thx :)

Could you maybe explain the negative look ahead? Im always eager to learn more.

Comment: Is it possible to skip more than one date this way?

Comment: @theweeknd it will skip all dates except the last. Or put another way, it will match the last date no matter how many dates are in the line.

Answer (score 0):

Use re.findall, take a look :

```
dates = re.findall(r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}', text)
```

re.findall provides you a list

first occurence is `dates[0]` and second occurence is `dates[1]`

look here : [return the second instance of a regex search in a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914002/return-the-second-instance-of-a-regex-search-in-a-line)